Yarn not installing dependencies
I am trying to install dependencies of a project but when I use the command yarn install I get the below error.
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@qureos/qureos- 
components/-/qureos-components-0.1.7.tgz: Request failed "404 Not Found"
    at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin 
(C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:696:66)
    at new ResponseError (C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:802:124)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:66750:16)
at Request.emit (node:events:519:28)
at module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:142287:10)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:698:27)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:540:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

I have even tried using the npm install command but I am getting the same above error. When I access the URL given in the error, it opens. Don't know what the problem is.
Edit: I have also used pnpm but still I get the same error that the URL is not found, but like I said when I type the URL in my browser and access it, it opens.
